# Is there a way to apply `Autocomplete` tabulator editor to <INPUT> tag and not tabulator cell?

Tags: tabulator

I like tabulator's `autocomplete` editor.

I can configure it for tabulator's cell: http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/edit#edit-builtin:

```json
    {title: "Example", field: "example",  editor: "autocomplete" }
```

Is there a way to apply `autocomplete` to `<input>` html element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `autocomplete` editor is already built off of an input element.

If you are asking if there is a way to use the editor outside of Tabulator as a stand alone component, then the answer **with in the Tabulator framework is no**, Tabulators editors are designed to work only with in the table itself.

That being said you could always have a look at the code for the editor and see if you could build it into a stand along library.

Comment: Thank you for answer. It would be nice to see this functionality as stand alone component, because `autocomplete` seems not tied to tabulator itself.